# need assistance with css layout

Tags: css, layout, html

I am having css layout issues.  I am attempting to align the Required! message to the right of the input elements

Keeping the flow:

Species:

> input element    error-message

Breed:

> input element    error-message

I tried various nested divs with-out success.

Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/d0773d/BpqyT/

Comment: What you're asking is still somewhat unclear.

Comment: There are lots of various issues here, but for starters, if you always put a line-break `<br />` in between two things you want next to each other, the second thing will always be forced **under** the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got too many unnecessary tags (list tags) in there please have a look at this, I think this will help:

```
<div style="float:left;">
<select>
    <option>testing</option>
</select>
    <span>Required</span>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<select>
    <option>testing</option>
</select>
    <span>Required</span>
</div>
```

working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BpqyT/7/

Comment: This was a start to figure out a correct way to format this.  I added clear:left; to the second div style which moved the second div under the first.

Comment: Oh you don't need any of the floats if you need them to be positioned vertically. remove them =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'text-align: right;' to make the message snap to the right of its available area.  But when you do that, it becomes evident that the parent containers don't line up vertically.  You'll need to re-work your markup and CSS.  Try one of these:

- Two div columns, "right" and "left" which contain either right or left halves of the content
- Getting rid of the container divs, and just using float and width to line everything up.

Comment: I took your idea into consideration, but after reworking my layout the Required! text was not lined up correctly.  So, I reworked my current layout to(see link to view): http://jsfiddle.net/d0773d/BpqyT/34/  I still was required to use <br /><br /> to move the other element and message below the first.

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that you wanted the Required! text aligned right below the input elements.

Answer (score 1):

**Quote:**  *"I am attempting to align the Required! message to the right of the input elements"*

You have a line break `<br />` in between which puts "Required!" on another line below the input element.

Answer (score 1):

This has got nothing to do with css, you have a `<br />` tag between the inputs and the error messages, you will have to remove these first.

Answer (score 0):

Divs are block-level elements, so they will force a new line by default. To correct this, change:

```
<div id="species_error">
```

and

```
<div id="breed_error">
```

to:

```
<div id="species_error" style="display:inline-block">
```

and

```
<div id="breed_error" style="display:inline-block">
```

Comment: Alternately, don't use divs for species_error and breed_error, and use spans. Spans are inline elements and will not force the line break.

Comment: I tried to implement display:inline-block, but did not force the div under the first one.

Comment: You said "I am attempting to align the Required! message to the right of the input elements." If you are trying to force the div under the first one, you would require a different answer.